# Review queue sizes are incorrect

Tags: support, bug, review, caching

The review queue sizes on the /review page on Stack Apps (and maybe other sites as well) are off. When I visit https://stackapps.com/review/ in a private browser window (or while logged in with a sockpuppet), I see that there is [1 item in the Low Quality Posts review queue and 1 in the Suggested Edits queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRYha.png). Yet when I or my fellow moderator rene view the page while logged in, they are [nowhere to be found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyoma.png).

I know that Low Quality Posts are sometimes invalidated for particular users after viewing them, but Suggested Edits ... There are no skipped items in my review history, and the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=default&site=stackapps&run=true) can't find them either. The last [suggested edit](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/7057) is from May 3rd already, so if this is some kind of caching, it's not configured properly.

Comment: Maybe it is caching for 6 to 8 weeks?

Comment: There are two review items there, both from 2020. The suggested edit baffles me and the LQP reciew... should be invalidated because the flag that created it was cleared? [1](https://stackapps.com/review/low-quality-posts/6501) [2](https://stackapps.com/review/suggested-edits/6385)

Comment: @animuson now I'm curious how you found those two review items. Could we have found them for ourselves?

Comment: They both showed up for me in the queues. *shrugs* No idea why.

Comment: Staff privileges it is  ;)

Comment: FWIW, I see the same review items in the queue (from 2020) as @animuson -- I haven't visited the Stack Apps review pages in a while, in case that is relevant.

Comment: @animuson thanks - I reviewed both of those *before* I became a moderator. But it still doesn't explain why rene doesn't...